# regex to remove all formatting

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex to remove everything except letters from a string.

E.g. `"Marys Page ...."` should become `"MarysPage"`

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using ([yes, it matters](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info))?

Answer (score 2):

The one that would be passed to tools like perl/sed/etc would be: s/[^a-zA-Z]//g

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `[^a-zA-Z]` with `""`.

Comment: @newbie_86, realize that for the input `café` the `é` is also stripped (in most cases).

Comment: that's ok. i'm expecting standard letters. using jquery/javascript

Comment: i tried:  return original.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/,"").trim(); doesn't strip out the white space :/

Comment: @new: You need to add the `g` flag after the `/` to replace _all_ matches.